# Explict Form of Ground State in Interacting Field Theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, vacuum, interactions, s-matrix-theory

In *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory* by *Peskin* and *Schroeder* chapter 4, it has discussed about the ground state $|\Omega\rangle$ (where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state in free field theory) in interacting field theory. As (4.27) shows,
$$|\Omega\rangle = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{iE_0T}\langle\Omega|0\rangle\right)^{-1}e^{-iHT}|0\rangle\tag{4.27}$$
And then there is a confusing derivation in (4.28),
$$|\Omega\rangle = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{iE_0T}\langle\Omega|0\rangle\right)^{-1}e^{-iH(T+t_0)}|0\rangle$$
$$= \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{iE_0T}\langle\Omega|0\rangle\right)^{-1}e^{-iH(t_0-(-T))}e^{-iH_0(-T-t_0)}|0\rangle$$
$$ = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty(1-i\epsilon)}\left(e^{iE_0T}\langle\Omega|0\rangle\right)^{-1}U(t_0, -T)|0\rangle\tag{4.28}$$
I got very confused about the derivation.

1. First, I'm not sure about add $t_0$ is valid or not, but I think if $T$ goes to infinity, add this term $t_0$ would be okay.
2. I got confused with the second line of the derivation, why it is accpectable to add $e^{-iH_0(-T-t_0)}$ in the equation, is the reason same as 1.?
3. I got confused with the apperance of $U(t_0, -T)$ and I think the order in second line is wrong, because in the previous text in the book, that is, eq(4.17), we define
   $$U(t, t_0) = e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}e^{-iH(t-t_0)}.\tag{4.17}$$ But in second line the order of $H$ and $H_0$ is different and the sign is a little bit different, too.
   Please help me figure out the confusing points above.

Related questions:

[Derivation of Peskin & Schroeder eq. (4.29)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/795329/)

[Imaginary time in QFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65323/)

Comment: Wow this derivation is so confusing that there are 4 separate questions about it in stack exchange. Working on an answer.

Comment: More on [eq. (4.27) in P&S](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bquantum-field-theory%5D+peskin+4.27).

Comment: Well, because I didn't expect the ground state for interacting field theory can be derived by this way, which is kind of reasonable from the point of veiw that it must relate to ground state in free theory, but I thought there would be more straight forward way to find it at the first sight. Many thanks! @JohnA.

Comment: Yeah, I am mostly criticizing Peskin, not the learner. Go Srednicki ! If you have a question about 4.29 (the dual), checkout the linked questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. First, I'm not sure about add 0 is valid or not, but I think if  goes to infinity, add this term 0 would be okay.

This is correct. Usually you see it used the opposite way, i.e. $x + X \approx X$ when $X>>x$ but here we are just doing $T \approx T +t_0$ since $T>>T_0$.

> I got confused with the second line of the derivation, why it is accpectable to add $^{−_0(−−_0)}$ in the equation, is the reason same as 1.?

No, you can add this because $H_0|0\rangle = 0$, i.e. $e^{xH_0}|0\rangle = |0\rangle .$

> I got confused with the apperance of $(_0,−)$

We can't use $U(t, t_0) = e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}e^{-iH(t-t_0)}$ here, it simply doesn't apply because we can't change $t_0$. Use Eq. (4.25) where we can set both times freely

$$U(t,t') = e^{iH_0(t-t_0)}e^{-iH(t-t')}e^{-iH_0(t'-t_0)}$$
so for
$$U(t_0, -T) = e^{iH_0(t_0-t_0)}e^{-iH(t_0-(-T))}e^{-iH_0((-T)-t_0)}$$
and we obtain whats needed.